# Unserialize data in array in Zend Framework 1

Tags: php, zend-framework, serialization

I've checked and can't find an answer to this question. I have a query which returns the values of 'content' from table 'linktagRevisions' for a given array of ID's. The query is looped though and the data is then output as a json string.

'content' is serialized, how can I unserialize and display in the json output?

Here is my code:

```
public function testAction()

{


    //Get latest revision from database and loop through $id's
    $id = array('308', '307', '306');

    //setup array and loop

    $result = array();

    foreach($id as $lId) {

        //Connect to database

        $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();

        //Perform Query
        $select = $db->select('')
            ->from(array('lr'=>'LinktagRevisions'),
            array('content'))
            ->where('linktagId = ?', $lId)
            ->order('updated DESC')
            ->limit(1);


        $stmt = $select->query();
        $result[$lId] = $stmt->fetch();


    }

    $this->_helper->json($result,true);
}
```

The standard error I get when trying different things is:

Warning: unserialize() expects parameter 1 to be string

Answer (score 0):

```
$phpNative = Zend_Json::decode($encodedValue);
$json = Zend_Json::encode($phpNative);
```

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.json.basics.html

Comment: Thankyou. But that doesn't seem to work. I tried $this->_helper->json::decode($result,true); but it does nothing. This is not really an issue with the json output as the data needs to be unserialized before it gets to this point in the script I would have thought.

Comment: try $this->_helper->json::decode($result,json::TYPE_OBJECT);

Comment: That removes the json output form the screen. I have unserialized the data in another function when I was only returning one row in a variable. The issue seems now to be only when I'm returning an array.

Comment: Try using a php function json_decode (http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). 
$results = json_decode($result); $this->_helper->json($results,true);

Comment: Not, this a bad solution

Comment: gives Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given